Sonos Spotify Connect Zeroconf AddUser Documentation
I'm trying to figure out how to specify the call parameters for a Sonos device to the Spotify Connect ZeroConf addUser endpoint, which is called to login to Spotify Connect for the specified device.  I'm currently using a Sonos IKEA Symfonisk (gen 2) device to test with, as well as a Spotify Premium account.
A Spotify Connect Zeroconf login needs to be done programmatically so that the Sonos device can be accessed by Spotify Connect after a period of inactivity.  The Sonos device automatically logs out of Spotify Connect after the inactivity period, and needs to be re-awakened (e.g. login again) in order to be selected.
In working with other vendors that support Spotify Connect (Bose, Onkyo, Yamaha, etc), they use a tokenType=accesstoken in the addUser parameters.  The blob parameter is formatted with a Spotify user-id and password value, and the addUser call successfully logs the user in to Spotify Connect for the device.  No problems with tokenType=accesstoken devices.
It appears that Sonos devices use a tokenType=authorization_code value in its addUser parameters.  The blob parameter is different for this token type than for a accesstoken token type.
What I would like to know is what to specify in the addUser parameters, namely the blob and the loginId parameters, for the authorization_code token type.  Based upon Wireshark traces when the Spotify desktop application is used ...

blob appears to be a (refresh?) token value.
loginId appears to be an SHA1 representation of a loginId value.

Spotify Connect addUser call to a Sonos device example:
&userName=31l77y ...redacted
&blob=AQC4E8xSTYmGAo2UK1dC6n4 ...redacted
&clientKey=
&tokenType=authorization_code
&loginId=f2860abad3313 ...redacted
&deviceName=THLUC ...redacted
&deviceId=80da4987232 ...redacted
&version=2.7.1

Thoughts?
Anybody else running into this?
Any documentation from a Sonos technical person?

Asking for off-site resources is off-topic on StackOverflow

Not sure what you mean by "off-site resources" ... I'm just looking for an example of how to login to Spotify Connect using a Sonos device that uses tokenType=authorization_code.  I also just noticed that you edited my post, removing text, etc.  Are you a bot?  This is my first post, so still learning.

Please have a look at [ask]. I've removed all the irrelevant details from your question
